# SQL (sqlalchemy) commit hangs but no concurrent processes accessing same session

Tags: python, sql, session, sqlalchemy

I have a program, whose main thread creates a child thread. The child thread has a while loop, in which it calls first to create a an entry in my db and then to query and insert back that entry.

I am using sqlalchemy as such:

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(connection_params)
try:
    Base.metadata.reflect(engine)
except OperationalError as ex:
    engine.dispose()
    raise ex
inspector = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

I also have a class inheriting from Base, which implements the following methods:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    with closing(Session()) as session:
        inst = cls(**kwargs)
        session.add(inst)
        session.commit()
        ret_val = inst.id
    return ret_val

@classmethod
def update(cls, entry_id, **kwargs):
    with closing(Session()) as session:
        entry = session.query(cls).filter_by(id=entry_id).first()
        # validate and update entry code...            
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(entry, k, v)
        session.commit()
```

Several users may be running the program at the same time, but each is using a unique entry_id (
the entry_id is always unique, due to this line: 
    inst = cls(**kwargs)

As I said, there is only one thread per user performing these operations so a session's transaction is always flushed.

**The problem:**
Somehow session.commit() started hanging (not returning from its call) because of the RLock on the operation. How is it possible that there was a block not released? How to prevent?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using InnoDB

Comment: Did you manage to figure out your hang?